# Python: readline() == string literal never returns True

Tags: python, file-io

**Edit: I made a simple error 'testing 1,2,3+\n' should be 'testing 1,2,3'+'\n' or 'testing 1,2,3\n'**

I'm trying to conditionally read text from a file.  I can't figure out a conditional that will return True when I compare my_file.readline() to some

**my_file.readline()  == 'string literal'** always returns false.

```
with open('text.txt','w') as my_file:
    my_file.write('testing 1,2,3'+'\n'+'filter me'+'\n')  #writing arbitrary text to my  file


with open('text.txt','r') as my_file:
    str_from_file = my_file.readline()        # first line should be 'testing 1,2,3'
    print str_from_file == 'testing 1,2,3+\n' #both print False
    print str_from_file == 'testing 1,2,3'    #what string literal would print true?
    print str_from_file
```

Obviously, I'm a huge nub with python & coding. This is my 5th day with Python.

Comment: Why is that `+` there? `'testing 1,2,3+\n'` should just be `'testing 1,2,3\n'.`

Comment: typo. was originally 'testing 1,2,3'+'\n'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're comparing the strings:

```
'testing 1,2,3'+'\n'  # 'testing 1,2,3\n'
```

and

```
'testing 1,2,3+\n'
```

Notice how the second string has an additional `'+'` character stuck in there.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping this wouldn't be a dumb mistake.